# There is a question about pymongo(cursor)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I use pymongo's cursor to traverse the database data, but with the `find ()` method, I only traverse 101 items, and then wait a long time to continue to traverse the next 100 items, then wait again.

```py
collection = client[db_name][collection_name]
count = 0
for i in collection.find():
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

There's not much data, only a few thousand.
This is a recent occurrence. There was no problem before.And if i use `find().batch_size(500)`,
it will first traverse 500, wait, traverse 500, wait until the last batch.

I put the code on the server to run, and it ran quickly, no problem. My friend's personal computer is OK, too.
So I was thinking, is this still a computer problem? I really can't understand, please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: The waiting time between prints it's normal. It's the time the data travels between mongodb to your computer. The main difference between your friend's computer and yours is the net connection, if your friend's connection is faster than yours, the wait time will be less.

Comment: @Roomm Thank you for your answer and what does this connection have to do with? Internet speed? But my internet speed is not slow.The waiting time is several minutes. It's very fast to connect mongodb. I feel that the problem lies in querying data. Querying the first batch of data is fast. The second round of traversal starts to wait